# Mocha Tags starting Protractor from Gulp

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, gulp, protractor

Trying to add for example `--grep @smoke` to my tests...

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
    gulp.src(["*.spec.js"])
        .pipe(protractor({
            configFile: "config.js"
        }))
        .on('error', function(e) { throw e })
});
```

I have tried many ways to pass in and it fails to ignore other tests. The example I want it to run...

```
it('should login as test user @smoke', async function() {
```

Any ideas? I believe if I ran the test using protractor cli instead of gulp it should work, but I need it in gulp for the project I am on.